# Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have async method in controller that calling the method from client. I want to iterate through this method in foreach loop but getting error:

```
*Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'*
```

**UnitTest.cs**

```
[TestFixture]
    public class ClientUnitTests 
    {
        private MessagesController Controller = new MessagesController(null, null, null);

        [Test]
        public async Task Check_API_Links()
        {
            // Arrange
            List<IEnumerable<string>> reporteeList = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();

            var links = await Controller.GetLinks();
            reporteeList.Add(links); //Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'
            foreach (var itemLink in reporteeList)
            {
                reporteeList.Add(itemLink);
            }

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(reporteeList);
            Assert.GreaterOrEqual(0, reporteeList.Count);
            Assert.IsInstanceOf<IEnumerable<string>>(reporteeList);
        }
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetLinks()
 {
   var result = await _client.GetLinks();

    return Ok(result);
 }
```

**Client.cs**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> GetLinks()
{
   // Some logic here, 
}
```

How can I resolve this to do iterate trought GetLinks method in unit test ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to wrap that into ActionResult

Answer (score 1):

Assuming .NET Core 2.1

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> GetLinks()
```

or the less preferred

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLinks()
```

Comment: I'v changed and add to client method but the same error in UnitTest

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, you embed `ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>` with `Ok` and `List<IEnumerable<string>>` with `IEnumerable<string>`.

For your current design, try code below:

```
        List<IEnumerable<string>> reporteeList = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
        var result = await controller.GetLinks();
        var links = ((ObjectResult)((ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>)((ObjectResult)result).Value).Result).Value as IEnumerable<string>;
        reporteeList.Add(links);
```

But, in my option, you should not use embed object. Please check whether below design meets your requirement.

Client.cs return `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>`

```
public class Client
{
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> GetLinks()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> links = new List<string>() {
            "L1","L2"
        };
        return new ObjectResult(links);
        // Some logic here, 
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetLinks1()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> links = new List<string>() {
            "L1","L2"
        };
        return links;
        // Some logic here, 
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetLinks1()
    {
        var result = await new Client().GetLinks1();
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Test

```
        List<string> reporteeList1 = new List<string>();
        var result1 = await controller.GetLinks1();
        var links1 = result1 as ObjectResult;
        reporteeList1.AddRange((IEnumerable<string>)links1.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsAllItemsCount()
    {
           // Act
       
        var result = await _controller.GetLinks1();
        var okResult = result.Result as OkObjectResult;

        // Assert
        var items = Assert.IsType<List<string>>(okResult.Value);
        Assert.Equal(2, items.Count);
    }
```